# VBA why infinite loop with MsgBox?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, infinite-loop, mathematical-optimization

If interested, goal of macro is to demonstrate Intermediate Value Theorem using computer (more powerful than demonstrating theorem by hand). Hence mathematical tag.

I have VBA macro with infinite loop of first MsgBox. Why is this infinite? I have tried relocating portions of code to fix this, seems to do nothing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Function1()
Dim Polynomial As String
Dim Sign
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Degree
Dim Coefficient

While Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value <> "" '+1 because top row occupied by column A, column B titles. If cell is empty stop.
counter = 1
MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
counter = counter + 1
Degree = Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value 'A2
Coefficient = Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value 'B2

If (Coefficient < 0) Then
Sign = " - " ' if coefficient negative
Else
If Coefficient > 0 Then Sign = " + " ' if coefficient positive
End If

Polynomial = Polynomial & " " & Coefficient & "x^" & Degree 'concatenation string, list polynomial.
counter = 1
counter = counter + 1
Wend
MsgBox Polynomial
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you setting `counter = 1`in multiple places? And why within the loop?

Comment: @findwindow I have tried setting counter in multiple places and it doesn't seem to work in any of them.

Comment: Oh ok. I don't know the theorem you cite so can't say when you want loop to stop but resetting counter within loop is most likely a bad idea :/ Also, your labels should get wiped because counter starts at 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run into an (unintentional) infinite loop, the first thing to check is the loop condition to see why it's never failing the condition and exiting.  In your case, that test is on the value of cells, but the bit that's important is the counter variable since that's what determines which cells (which are presumably not changing values during this).

If you'll walk through the program by hand, you'll see that you're setting it to 1 in multiple places, which essentially resets it each time through the loop. So even though you increment it, the next time through it goes back to 1 and you start all over.  As a general rule for counters, you want to set the initial value once just outside (above) the loop, and then increment it at the end of the body of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, explains problem exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying your counter in inappropriate places. Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Function1()
Dim Polynomial As String
Dim Sign
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Degree
Dim Coefficient

counter = 1
While Cells(counter, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(counter, 2).Value <> ""
    MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
    Degree = Cells(counter, 1).Value 'A2
    Coefficient = Cells(counter, 2).Value 'B2

    If (Coefficient < 0) Then
    Sign = " - " ' if coefficient negative
    Else
    If Coefficient > 0 Then Sign = " + " ' if coefficient positive
    End If

    Polynomial = Polynomial & " " & Coefficient & "x^" & Degree 'concatenation string, list polynomial.
    counter = counter + 1
Wend
MsgBox Polynomial
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but explanation would have been nice.